# dealing with python global variables when using recursive functions

Tags: python, global-variables

I made a program that extracts the text from a HTML file. It recurses down the HTML document and returns the list of tags. For eg,

input   **< li >no way < b > you < /b > are doing this < /li >**

output   **['no','way','you','are'...]**.

Here is a highly simplified pseudocode for this:

```
def get_leaves(node):
    kids=getchildren(node)
    for i in kids:
        if leafnode(i):
            get_leaves(i)
        else:
            a=process_leaf(i)
            list_of_leaves.append(a)

def calling_fn():
    list_of_leaves=[] #which is now in global scope
    get_leaves(rootnode)
    print list_of_leaves
```

I am now using **list_of_leaves in a global scope** from the calling function. The calling_fn() declares this variable, get_leaves() appends to this.

**My question is**, how do I modify my function so that I am able to do something like list_of_leaves=get_leaves(rootnode), ie without using a global variable?

I dont want each instance of the function to duplicate the list, as the list can get quite big.

Please dont critisize the design of this particular pseudocode, as I simplified this. It is meant for another purpose: extracting tokens along with associated tags using BeautifulSoup

Comment: Have you considered a HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: At least from your pseudocode it doesn't seem list_of_leaves is global.

Comment: Please don't consider this a criticism -- it's not, but check out the output of this python expression (after importing re, of course): `re.split(r'<.*?>', "< li >no way < b > you < /b > are doing this < /li >")`

Comment: I AM using BeautifulSoup. And using regexes for HTML parsing turned out to be a very touchy topic, my account got temporarily suspended due to negative votes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass the result list as optional argument.

```
def get_leaves(node, list_of_leaves=None):
    list_of_leaves = [] if list_of_leaves is None else list_of_leaves
    kids=getchildren(node)
    for i in kids:
        if leafnode(i):
            get_leaves(i, list_of_leaves)
        else:
            a=process_leaf(i)
            list_of_leaves.append(a)

def calling_fn():
    result = [] 
    get_leaves(rootnode, list_of_leaves=result)
    print result
```

Python objects are always passed by reference. This has been discussed before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference). Some of the built-in types are immutable (e.g. `int`, `string`), so you cannot modify them in place (a new string is created when you concatenate two strings and assign them to a variable). Instance of mutable types (e.g. `list`) can be modified in place. We are taking advantage of this by passing the original list for accumulating result in our recursive calls.

For extracting text from HTML in a real application, using a mature library like `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml.html` is always a much better option (as others have suggested).

Comment: I think you would be better of using : if list_of_leaves is None: list_of_leaves = []. For example the code: x = [] ;a = x or 'test' (assigns test to a). So that would mean the result list (in the calling function) would be still empty and what you are populating is a separate list in the method 'get_leaves'

Comment: Does this pass list_of_leaves by reference? Could you explain it?

Comment: @aitchnyu: explanation added.

Answer (score 8):

No need to pass an accumulator to the function or accessing it through a global name if you turn `get_leaves()` into a generator:

```
def get_leaves(node):
    for child in getchildren(node):
        if leafnode(child):
            for each in get_leaves(child):
                yield each
        else:
            yield process_leaf(child)

def calling_fn():
    list_of_leaves = list(get_leaves(rootnode))
    print list_of_leaves
```

Comment: This is the best answer, as it lets you consume the data without storing it all up-front at all.

Comment: I think this is the most elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Use a decent HTML parser like BeautifulSoup instead of trying smarter than existing software.

Answer (score 2):

@pillmincher's generator answer is the best, but as another alternative, you can turn your function into a class:

```
class TagFinder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.leaves = []

    def get_leaves(self, node):
        kids = getchildren(node)
        for i in kids:
            if leafnode(i):
                self.get_leaves(i)
            else:
                a = process_leaf(i)
                self.list_of_leaves.append(a)
def calling_fn():
    finder = TagFinder()
    finder.get_leaves(rootnode)
    print finder.list_of_leaves
```

Your code likely involves a number of helper functions anyway, like  `leafnode`, so a class also helps group them all together into one unit.

Answer (score 1):

As a general question about recursion, this is a good one.  It is common to have a recursive function that accumulates data into some collection.  Either the collection needs to be a global variable (bad) or it is passed *to* the recursive function.  When collections are passed in almost every language, only a reference is passed so you do not have to worry about space.  Someone just posted an answer showing how to do this.